# steps to migrate pvcs to svn

Tags: svn, pvcs

please provide steps to migrate from pvcs to svn. I have googled for the open source tools and found polarion pvcs2svn tool. if someone has used this software, please provide the steps followed and the config.properties file used. I am finding it difficult to use this software. Even I am not receiving any help from the forum of this product.

Answer (score 0):

This tool is quite simple to use. Based on version 1.3 i'm posting some of changes i did on our  current config.properties file:

```
# Import dump settings
import_dump_into_svn=yes
clear_svn_parent_dir=yes
use_only_last_revision_content=no
file_description_property_key=description
use_file_copy=yes

# FILE SETTINGS
full.dump.file=full_dump_%date%.txt
incr.dump.file=incr_dump_%date%.txt
incr.history.file=incr_history.txt
list.files.to=files_%date%.txt
dump.file.sizelimit.mb=400

# SVN DUMP OPTIONS
trunk_path=trunk
branches_path=branches
tags_path=tags
svnimporter_user_name=svn_user
only_trunk=no

# SVN AUTOIMPORT OPTIONS
svnadmin.executable=svnadmin.exe
svnadmin.repository_path=E:/Repositories/OUR_REPO
svnadmin.parent_dir=.
svnadmin.tempdir=e:/temp/svn/local
svnclient.executable=svn.exe
svnadmin.verbose_exec=yes
svn.log.dateformat=dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
svnadmin.path_not_exist_signature=non-existent in that revision

# PVCS PROVIDER CONFIGURATION #
pvcs.class=org.polarion.svnimporter.pvcsprovider.PvcsProvider
pvcs.executable=pcli.exe
pvcs.projectpath=D:/PVCS/OUR_REPO
pvcs.subproject=
pvcs.tempdir=e:/temp/local_migration
pvcs.checkouttempdir=e:/temp/pvcs_migration
pvcs.log.dateformat=dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
pvcs.log.datelocale=en
pvcs.log.encoding=utf-8
pvcs.log.datetimezone=Europe/Berlin
pvcs.verbose_exec=yes
pvcs.username=ouruser
pvcs.password=ourpass
# pvcs.keep_vlogfile=yes
# pvcs.import_attributes=yes
pvcs.validate_checkouts=yes
```

After setting those details, you have to change the  **pvcs.log.dateformat** , **pvcs.log.encoding** and **pvcs.log.datetimezone** based on the server timezone.

And then, you must run one of the following commands in order to start the migration.

Linux
    run.sh  full config.properties

Windows
    run.bat  full config.properties

I hope it helps ( and sorry for my english :) )