# Is there any document for migrating code from PVCS to github with history?

Tags: github, pvcs

what is the best way to migrate the code from serena pvcs to github? Do I need to migrate the code first to svn then migrate to github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't have to migrate "to GitHub" directly: you can migrate to a local Git repo, and then push that Git repo to a new empty GitHub repository.

Second, from [this thread](https://www.serenacentral.com/community/forums/serena-migration-to-another-code-versioning-system-git) or [this one](https://www.serenacentral.com/community/forums/serena-changeman-dimension-9-1-to-git-migration), there is no dedicated tool for directly importing that VCS to a Git repo.
If you know of a way to import to an SVN repo first, then you can use a tool like [SubGit](https://subgit.com/) (free for a one-time import) to import the SVN repo to a Git repo.

Comment: Ok. can you tell me how can I migrate history to git local?

Comment: @KV9 Once you have migrated your PVCS to SVN (a local SVN repo) with https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/svn/svn_importer and/or https://stackoverflow.com/a/24697138/6309, create a local git repo (cd afolder; git init .) and follow https://subgit.com/documentation/howto.html

Comment: Is there anyway to migrate the source code directly from pvcs to git without moving to svn? or Do i need to follow these migration (pvcs->svn->git)

Comment: @KV9 It is preferable to use the pvcs->svn->git path. But if you don't have to import *all* the history (only the major points), then you can follow the advices in https://www.serenacentral.com/community/forums/serena-changeman-dimension-9-1-to-git-migration, to import directly in a new local Git repo, and use a similar process than https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537412/6309